# ¿como obtengo el sexo con facebook API?

Tags: javascript, facebook-api

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
FB.api("/me", "GET", {
    "fields":"gender"}, 
    (res) => {
        console.log(res.gender)
})
```

pero me da `undefined`, tengo configurado todo lo demás, pero quiero obtener el sexo de la persona, ¿como lo hago?

Comment: cómo obtengo sexo con facebook api... no espera... leí mal :P

Comment: Lee la documentación, no lo he puesto en practica asi que no creo poder aportar mucho al respecto
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user

Answer (score 3):

En la documentación indica la forma de realizarlo usando el payload

```
FB.api(
    "/<CUSTOM_AUDIENCE_ID>/users",
    "POST",
    {
        "payload": "{\"schema\":[\"EMAIL\",\"LOOKALIKE_VALUE\"],\"data\":[[\"9b431636bd164765d63c573c346708846af4f68fe3701a77a3bdd7e7e5166254\",44.5],[\"8cc62c145cd0c6dc444168eaeb1b61b351f9b1809a579cc9b4c9e9d7213a39ee\",140],[\"4eaf70b1f7a797962b9d2a533f122c8039012b31e0a52b34a426729319cb792a\",0],[\"98df8d46f118f8bef552b0ec0a3d729466a912577830212a844b73960777ac56\",0.9]]}"
    },
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* Realiza algo con el resultado */
      }
    }
);
```

El resultado depende del género definido por el usuario puede ser `male` o `female`.

Te sugiero usar el explorador de la API Graph para realizar pruebas

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

es importante comentar que aunque realices la petición de ciertos valores, estos en ocasiones no pueden ser obtenidos si el usuario no los especifica no permite sean obtenidos.

Este sería un ejemplo real usando JavaScript

```
FB.api(
  '/me',
  'GET',
  {"fields":"id,name,gender,email"},
  function(response) {
      // Insert your code here
  }
);
```

Puedes revisar mas información en la [documentación](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user)